# “unresolved dependency” for Spark 2.1.0 on SBT

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

> version := "1.0"
>  scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
>  ivyScala :=
>   ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true) }
>   libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"

I try to get spark into my develop environment, when i try to assembly jar by sbt, but it failed and showed [error] in my sbt just like below:

```
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: <br/>
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: <br/>
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: <br/>
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.1.0: not found <br/>
[warn]  :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: <br/>
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path: <br/>
[warn]      org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.1.0  (D:\MyDocument\IDEA\Scala\model\build.sbt#L9-10) <br/>
[warn]        +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:2.1.0 <br/>
[warn]        +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.1.0 (D:\MyDocument\IDEA\Scala\model\build.sbt#L15-16) <br/>
[warn]        +- org.apache.spark:spark-hive_2.11:2.1.0 (D:\MyDocument\IDEA\Scala\model\build.sbt#L11-12) <br/>
[warn]        +- default:producttagmodel_2.11:1.0 <br/>
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output. <br/>
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;2.1.0: not found
```

my IntelliJ version is 2016.3.5, and sbt version is 0.13.13 and scala version is 2.11.8; i found that sbt have download the spark-core.jar successfully which i find it in my .ivy/cache directory, but it always show "unknown artifact. Not Resovled or Indexed". I have refresh my project index many times but it didn't work.  i create a new project by using the same build.sbt in case of the IntelliJ cache disturb, but it didn't work. I am totally confused of this problem. 
    here is my build.sbt setting below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the dependency to :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

In addition for a spark app, this is normally added as `"provided"`, it should not be included in the jar, as when you submit your job, the related spark libs are installed already in driver and executors.

Comment: yes, I have tried the dependency as the format of yours before I submit this problem . But unfortunately, it didn't work, so as mine.